# Did Mordechai go to Eretz Yisrael and return to Persia?

Tags: mordechai

In his first year, Cyrus permits the Jews to return to Israel.

Ezra 2:2
[Those] who came with Zerubbabel, Jeshua, Nehemiah, Seraiah, Reelaiah, Mordecai Bilshan, Mispar, Bigvei, Rehum, Baanah, the number of the important men of the people of Israel.

The Gemara says Mordechai Bilshan is the Mordechai from the Megillah.

Cyrus ruled Persia for 20 years. According to Jewish understanding, Darius ruled after him and only then did Achashverosh take the throne.

Did Mordechai come to Israel and return to Persia some time in the ~23 +years after?

Comment: I remember seeing that Mordechai returned to Bavel to take care of Esther after her parents died.

Comment: Re: your penultimate paragraph. Traditional Jewish understanding (Seder Olam) has the chronology Cyrus - Achashverosh - Darius. Also note that presumably Cyrus granted permission to return to Israel in the first year after he conquered the Neo-Babylonian empire, many years after he first took the throne of Persia.

Answer (score 7):

[Ralbag to Ezra 2:2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ralbag_on_Ezra.2.2.3?lang=he) explains that Mordechai did indeed return to Persia after coming to Israel:

> ואל תתמה איך יצא מירושלים אחר שנכנס שם כי מפני השטנה שכתבו אחשורוש ושאר מלכי פרס להשבית המלאכה הוצרכו לצאת משם להשתדל בכל עז בהשלמת הבנין אחר שימצאו חן בעיני מלכי פרס:‏
>
> Don't ask, "how did he [Mordechai] leave Jerusalem after he had gone there?" Rather, due to the libel that was written by Achashverosh and the other Persian kings to halt the work [of builing the Temple], he [Mordechai] had to leave there [Jerusalem] and work with all his might for the completion of the Temple by finding favor in the eyes of the Persian kings.

Comment: ... which just sets the mood for the Book of Esther even further; imagine how he'd felt having made it to the Promised Land ... then slid backwards. It's easy to see how a lot of Jews had lost hope by then.

Answer (score 2):

The straightforward answer to your question is Yes.

[Here](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Esther/2.6#e0n6:%7E:text=%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%9B%D7%90%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%92%D7%B3%20%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D%3A%20%D7%B4%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%D7%B4%2C%20%D7%B4%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%94%D7%B4%2C%20%D7%B4%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%B4%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A2%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%91%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%A5%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%2C%20%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9D%20%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A8%20%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%92%D7%B3%20%D7%A4%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D) the Vilna Gaon mentions that Mordechai actually went back and forth between Yerushalayim and galus THREE times.

Mordechai was living in Yerushalayim and actively contributing to the reconstruction efforts sanctioned by King Cyrus, found himself facing a "stop work order" devised by Haman and his eleven sons, including the scribe Shimshai. Undeterred, Mordechai journeyed to Shushan with the aim of persuading the authorities to rescind the stop work order and permit the ongoing reconstruction of the beis hamikdash.

This is mentioned in [Midrash Panim Acheirim](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Aggadah_on_Esther%2C_Midrash_Panim_Acherim%2C_Version_II.1?lang=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%96%D7%91%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%2C-,%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9,-%2C%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99), as well as in [Yalkut Shimoni](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.1045.2?lang=bi&with=Navigation&lang2=he#:%7E:text=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%96%D7%91%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%2C%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%98%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%A8%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F%2C%20%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9A%20%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%96%D7%91%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%20%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%92%D7%93%D7%9F%2C%20%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%2C%20%D7%95%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%98%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9A%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%95%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%97%D7%9C%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%9C%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9A%20%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%95%D7%99%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9).

I believe the [Ralbag on Ezra](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezra.2.2?lang=bi&with=Ralbag&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99.%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%91%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C%20%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9A%20%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%90%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%20%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A1%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%20%D7%9C%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%93%D7%9C%20%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%96%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%97%D7%9F%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A1) gives this understanding in his commentary.

(If my understanding of these events is skewed, someone please do correct them, Thank You)